How do I add an icon to a react-big-calendar event?
I am using React Icons and React-big-calendar.  I am successfully rendering the calendar via an API to fill dates, times, and event titles.  I would like to supplement the title with an icon.  I have installed React Icons and can render icons like this:  <FaCircleCheck /> etc.
I would like to return the appropriate icon in the title from the API and have it rendered as title <icon />.  The API is successfully returning the title itself with the appropriate icon code in the title field.  My issue is it renders the icon text, but not the icon itself, like this:
This is the Title <FaCircleCheck />
I must be missing something basic, or I may need to use the titleAccessor capability but am at a loss with how to accomplish this.
Thanks!

Can you provide the code snippet example of your current implementation of Calendar component

Does your API return event titles literally in the format This is the Title <FaCircleCheck />? If yes, even if you could get it to work, I would generally recommend against this approach because of possible injection attacks.
Instead, one way to do it would be to have your API return the icon name in a separate field, and then use a whitelist approach to map it to the matching icon component. You can use the components prop of Calendar to specify a renderer for the event contents, which could parse the icon name and render the icon based on that name.
You can get started with using the components prop here: https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/examples--example-8
Source code referenced on the above page: https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/blob/master/stories/demos/exampleCode/rendering.js
